Understanding the map between homotopy classes for the two sheeted self covering of the torus
Consider the rectangles $\left[0,2\right] \times \left[0, 1 \right]$ and $\left[0,1 \right] \times \left[ 0 , 1 \right]$ with appropriate quotients to make it into tori with the standard topology. Call the first space space $T_1$ and second $T_2$. Consider the function between the two rectangles $f(\begin{bmatrix} x\\ y \end{bmatrix}) = \begin{bmatrix} \frac{x}{2} \\ y \end{bmatrix}$. Clearly this induces a function between the tori.
Now, I wish to understand the induced map between homotopy classes $f^*$ induced by $f$. It acts by sending homotopy classes to homotopy classes in the following way:
$$f^*( \left[\alpha \right]_{T_1} ) = \left[f(\alpha) \right]_{T_2}$$
Now consider the path on $T_1$ which moves on the $x$-axis
$\gamma (t) = \begin{cases} \begin{bmatrix} 2t  \\0\end{bmatrix} , t \in \left[ 0, 1 \right]\end{cases}$
Remark: The above map is actually between unit interval and rectangle, but consider the unique map corresponding to it from the unit interval to $T_1$.
Of course, $\gamma(t)$ is homotopic to the constant map to $T_1$, i.e: $c(t) = \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}$
But now the problem is that the image of these are in different homotopy class in $T_2$ although they are in different ones in $T_1$, $c(t)$ goes to the homotopy class of identity and $\gamma$ goes to the homotopy classes of loops which go across once through $T_2$.
Did I make a mistake? Aren't all maps in the same homotopy class supposed to map to the same thing?

Why do you think that $f\circ \gamma$ goes all the way across $T_2$? It looks to me like it goes halfway across and comes back again.

By the way, the standard notation of a topologist for a point in $\mathbb R^n$ is just a tuple written horizontally, e.g. $(2t,0)$, rather than the linear algebra standard notation of a column vector $\begin{bmatrix}2t \ 0 \end{bmatrix}$.

There's a lot of confusion here. First of all, you should note that your map $f$ is a homeomorphism, so essentially you could stop here and move on. It is not a two-sheeted covering map as your title suggests.
As for the example you came up with, it does not stand up to scrutiny: It isn't "of course" homotopic to a constant map, at least not relative its endpoints (any path is freely homotopic to a constant one so I'm assuming this is what you mean); in fact, it represents one of the two "standard" generators of $\pi_1(T_1)$.
As for the homotopy classes in $T_2$, first of all it's not true that $c$ goes to the "homotopy class of the identity," in fact this statement does not even parse since the identity is a function $T_2 \to T_2$ (if you mean "goes to the identity element of $\pi_1(T_2)$" you should say so, but I would probably say "goes to 0 (or 1)," depending on whether you consider $\pi_1(T_2)$ as an abelian group or not, or simply that $f_*([c])$ is trivial). What "goes across once through $T_2$" is supposed to mean is somewhat unclear to me, but if you essentially mean "gets mapped to one of the 'standard' generators of $\pi_1(T_2)$", then this is correct.
To sum up, there's no issue here: You claimed $\gamma$ was nullhomotopic, but this is false, and thus the problem disappears.

I believe that $\gamma$ is nullhomotopic relative to free homotopy. Are you sure it's not?

How could I be sure it's not if in my answer I'm explicitly saying it is freely nullhomotopic? Please read paragraph two again, carefully.

I can't believe it. How can the constant path be homotopic to the any one of the ones generated by either free generator? Could you give the homotopy for this?

Convince yourself (or look it up) that if $X \simeq Y$, then $[X, Z] \cong [Y, Z]$ for all spaces $Z$, and apply this to  $[0, 1] \simeq *$. If you want something explicit, pick a deformation retraction of $[0, 1]$ onto ${0}$ and work through how the bijection above works.

I thought about it more and I see now. But, what exactly does the notation $\left[ X, Z\right]$ mean?

@CantorDustDrachen It's the set of (free) homotopy classes of maps $X \to Z$. It's bog standard and you should be able to find it in pretty much any book.
